# Tampermonkey script doesn't load if tab is in background (Firefox)

Tags: javascript, tampermonkey

I've created a Tampermonkey script that injects a button into the webpage and downloads a textfile when you click it. Everything works fine. But if the tab loads in the background (e.g. you open a new tab without jumping to it) the button does not appear.

There is no difference between

```
// @run-at       document-idle
```

and

```
// @run-at       document-start
```

but if I inject the button to a static element

```
document.body.appendChild(button)
```

instead of

```
document.getElementsByClassName("sc-181ts2x-0")[0].appendChild(button)
```

it works 100% of the time in the background

I assume this is because the Element that I'm trying to add the button to does not exist when it loads, but this only happens when the tab is in the background and

```
// @run-at       document-idle
```

should make sure it only runs once everythin is loaded

```
// @name         Pixiv Description Downloader
// @namespace    http://tampermonkey.net/
// @version      0.5
// @description  Downloads captions/descriptions from pixiv to a work_title(pixiv_id).txt. The format is the same as that of PXdownloader, which does not support captions.
// @author       UglyGoblin
// @include      https://www.pixiv.net/member_illust.php?*
// @grant        none
// @require      https://raw.githubusercontent.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js/master/dist/FileSaver.js
// @run-at       document-idle
// ==/UserScript==

(function() {
    'use strict';

     window.addEventListener('load', () => {
    addButton('\<b\>↓ Description \<\/b\>', downloadDescriptionFN)
    })
//insert button
    function addButton(text, onclick, cssObj) {
        cssObj = cssObj || {position: 'relative', right:'10px', top:'2px','z-index': 3}
        let button = document.createElement('button'), btnStyle = button.style
//add button next to PXdownloader button
        document.getElementsByClassName("sc-181ts2x-0")[0].appendChild(button)
        button.innerHTML = text
        button.onclick = onclick
//make button background transparent
        button.style.background = "none";
        button.style.border = "none";
        Object.keys(cssObj).forEach(key => btnStyle[key] = cssObj[key])
        return button
    }
//actual function to download on button press
    function downloadDescriptionFN() {
         //get url of current tab
         var url = window.location.href;
         //get the pixiv id from url
         var pixivID = url.split('illust_id=')[1];
         //get title of artwork
         var title = document.getElementsByClassName("sc-1u8nu73-3 igWZKS")[0].textContent;
         //add pixiv it to title => title(pixiv_id).txt
         var textfile = title.concat('\(',pixivID,'\).txt');
         //get captions as html
         var rawHTML = document.getElementsByClassName("_3BeBvbu");
         //replace <br> with \n
         var textWithLineBreaks = rawHTML[0].innerHTML.replace(/\<br\>/gi,"\n");
         //add title as title to textfile (for some reason needs 2 linebreaks to work)
         var finalTXT = title.concat("\n","\n",textWithLineBreaks);
         //create new blob with content of captions
         var blob = new Blob([finalTXT], {type: "text/plain;charset=utf-8"})
         //save the blob as textfile with the name title(pixiv).txt
         saveAs(blob, textfile)

    }
})();
```

Answer (score 1):

The solution was to use jQuery and waitForKeyElements and replace

```
window.addEventListener('load',
```

with

```
waitForKeyElements(".sc-181ts2x-0",
```

the button now loads successfully every time